# Site load delay

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-exchange, maintenance

Today at 19.50 GMT:

Some sites are taking more than two minutes to load content, including the questions page and individual questions, including:

[science fiction and fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions),

[medical sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions).

and  [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

This did not apply to all sites, biology for example seemed OK.

My  local network allowed hi-res video streaming at this time, so not an issue at this end directly.

This seems to have resolved at present, 20.10 GMT , the time of posting this - so will likely result in no-repro now.

Temporary glitch or sign of something more concerning?

Comment: I looked for evidence of this from our side (long-running queries or query timeouts, page timeouts and other exceptions, etc.) and found none. So, hopefully this was just a brief issue isolated to you.

Comment: Sure, so many links in the chain between us all. Not difficult for a weak one to get twitchy anywhere in-between. @AaronBertrand